# How to merge multiple docx with different header

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I have multiple docx files, each file with different header. How could I merge all of them, but keeping each file header?

I tried  with `header.is_linked_to_previous = False`, but no change.

```
def combine_docs(self):
    print("COMBINING...")
    files = sorted(os.listdir(output))
    result = Document(output + files[0])
    result.add_page_break()

    composer = Composer(result)

    for i in range(1, len(files)):
        doc = Document(output + files[i])

        if i != len(files) - 1:
            doc.add_page_break()

        composer.append(doc)

    composer.save(output + "combined.docx")
```